# Reassign an array of classes indexes (reference type)

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

Consider the following code:

```
internal class A
{
     public int X;
}

private void test()
{
     A[] Collection = new A[2];
     Collection[0].X = 1;
     Collection[1] = Collection[0]
     Collection[0] = new A();
     Collection[0].X = 2;
     //The code above produces: Collection[1] displays 2, and Collection[0] displays 2.
     //Wanted behaviour: Collection[1] should display 1, and Collection[0] display 2.
}
```

Since the array of classes, *Collection*, is a reference type. *Collection[0]* points to same memory region that *Collection[1]* does.

**My question is,** *how can i "copy" Collection[0] values to Collection[1] so i get the following output:*

*Collection[1].X* returns 1, and *Collection[0].X* returns 2.

Comment: Well you just avoid writing the code in the way you have done... just `Collection` (which isn't an idiomatic local variable name, by the way) to have two separate references, and initialize each of those objects how you want to. The code would look nothing like it does now. It doesn't help that your comments talk about `Collection[2]` which would be out of range...

Comment: your code throws a NullReferenceException, first initialize the `Collection[0]` then try to compile it and see, it will show you what you want.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is marked down - it is reasonably clear and useful.  Could the person marking it down please explain?

Comment: "//The code above produces: Collection[1] displays 2, and Collection[0] displays 2." .. I don't believe this

Comment: The snippet above should do what you want (ignoring the NRE). Paste the actual code.

Comment: @LewsTherin: I think the original post was edited.

Comment: Wow, I thought people would understand the question. Should perhaps mentioned it was psuedo code. My apologizies.
Sorry for making an unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

here is a example

```
internal class A
{
     public int X;
}

private void test()
{
     A[] Collection = new A[2];
     Collection[0].X = 1;
       CopyPropertyValues(Collection[0],Collection[1]);
     Collection[0] = new A();
     Collection[0].X = 2;

}




public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object destination)
{
    var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
        {
            if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name && 
        destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
            {
                destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(
                    source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The op understands reference semantics (re-read the question again) - the op is asking for the standard way to achieve what he/she wants.

Answer (score -1):

You should have class 'A' implement a 'Clone' method and then instead of:

```
Collection[1] = Collection[0];
```

use:

```
Collection[1] = Collection[0].Clone();
```

Alternatively, you could change class 'A' to a struct, but that would have other unintended consequences.